# SyntaxError at / invalid syntax (forms.py, line 6)

Tags: django, django-forms

```
from django import forms


class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):
  first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'})
  last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name'})
  address     = models.CharField(max_length=75, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address'})
  address2    = models.CharField(max_length=75, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address 2'})
  postcode    = models.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Postcode'})
  phone       = models.IntegerField(max_length=15, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number'})
```

SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (forms.py, line 6)

This is properly a school boy error but can't seem to get it to go away.

Comment: Each line, you forget to close a bracket :)

Comment: You have no idea how long I have spent, thanks, if you post it as an answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: And you used model fields, instead of form fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each line, you open *two* brackets:

1. one for the form *field*; and
2. one for the widget.

But at the end of the line, you only close *one* bracket, so at every line, you need to add an extra closing bracket.

You also used `models.` for the field, instead of `forms.`. These are different, since `models.` are used for database columns, whereas `forms.` encapsulate an item in a (HTML) form.

```
from django import forms

class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):

  first_name  = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
  last_name   = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Last Name'}))
  address     = forms.CharField(max_length=75, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Address'}))
  address2    = forms.CharField(max_length=75, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Address 2'}))
  postcode    = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Postcode'}))
  phone       = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Mobile Number'}))
```